# работа с консолью браузера

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с такой проблемой . В общем есть "Почти программа" , суть ее заключается что бы заходить на сайт и кликать по определенному html элементу . Имеется почти стандартный букет библиотек ViKing.Engine , Leaf.xNet , System.Net . Весь рунет перерыл и не нашел как из программы выполнить js скрипт в консоли браузера . (Selenium и другое не предлагать)

Comment: `Selenium и другое не предлагать` и другое - это что конкретно не предлагать? Что сами то пробовали? Какие требования к вашей задачи и чем вам селениум не подошел?

Comment: [WebBrowser.InvokeScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.invokescript) предлагать?

Comment: вам CefSharp нужен